# Sort 2d Array based on values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i have a huge 2d array with the coordiantes of vertexes of hexagons.
which looks like this:

```
let arr = [
  [150.3073578016,95.9815785601,149.1526572632,97.9815785601,150.3073578016,99.9815785601,152.6167588783,99.9815785601,153.7714594167,97.9815785601,152.6167588783,95.9815785601],
  [120.5738189383,54.4815785601,121.7285194767,54.4815785601,122.3058697459,55.4815785601,121.7285194767,56.4815785601,120.5738189383,56.4815785601,119.9964686691,55.4815785601],
  [119.9964686691,78.4815785601,122.3058697459,78.4815785601,123.4605702842,80.4815785601,122.3058697459,82.4815785601,119.9964686691,82.4815785601,118.8417681307,80.4815785601],
  [115.6663416502,100.9815785601,117.9757427269,100.9815785601,119.1304432653,102.9815785601,117.9757427269,104.9815785601,115.6663416502,104.9815785601,114.5116411118,102.9815785601],
  [124.326595688,100.9815785601,126.6359967648,100.9815785601,127.7906973032,102.9815785601,126.6359967648,104.9815785601,124.326595688,104.9815785601,123.1718951496,102.9815785601],
];
```

a hexagon has 6 vertexes. each subarray is a hexagon and has the x and y coordiantes of each vertex point.

so each sub-array contains 12 values.

**Note: Not all hexagons have the same size!**

structured like this (**UNSORTED**!): `[x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y];`

My problem now is: how can I sort the 2d array so that i have it ordered row-wise, going from top-left to bottom-right?
[image]

My idea was to just sum each sub value, but it doesn't give me the order that i want.

```
function sortHexagons(hexCoordinates) {
  function sort(arr) {
    const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
    return arr.reduce(reducer);
  }
  hexCoordinates.sort((a, b) => sort(a) - sort(b));
}
```

Comment: You mean you need to sort each and every inner arrays?

Comment: If you just want to sort row-wise, find the minimum x value of each hexagon array, then sort all of the arrays by their minimum x value. Obviously this assumes that your hexagons are uniform in width

Comment: @SajeebAhamed yes, each sub-array resembles a hexagon. i need the list to go row-wise from left to right

Comment: Assuming the order of vertices is the same you can ignore everything besides the first vertice/xy pair. Sort the hexagons by x and y, like `return b[1] > a[1]` if the difference is not zero otherwise `b[0] - a[0]`.

Comment: *"row-wise from left to right"*: That is ambiguous. When do you consider two hexagons to belong to the same row? If they have the same max y-coordinate? Or the same min-y-coordinate? Or the same y-coordinate for their centres? ...

Comment: It is also not clear whether you want to extract coordinates from each hexagon, and just get an ordered list of vertexes, or whether you want to keep the hexagon coordinates in groups of 12 as they are now and just order the outer array of them, or still something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an untested attempt. I average the x and y values of each hexagon, then order first by y descending, and second by x ascending. Makes assumptions about the uniformity of your hexagons.

```
    var arr = [
    [150.3073578016,95.9815785601,149.1526572632,97.9815785601,150.3073578016,99.9815785601,152.6167588783,99.9815785601,153.7714594167,97.9815785601,152.6167588783,95.9815785601],
    [120.5738189383,54.4815785601,121.7285194767,54.4815785601,122.3058697459,55.4815785601,121.7285194767,56.4815785601,120.5738189383,56.4815785601,119.9964686691,55.4815785601],
    [119.9964686691,78.4815785601,122.3058697459,78.4815785601,123.4605702842,80.4815785601,122.3058697459,82.4815785601,119.9964686691,82.4815785601,118.8417681307,80.4815785601],
    [115.6663416502,100.9815785601,117.9757427269,100.9815785601,119.1304432653,102.9815785601,117.9757427269,104.9815785601,115.6663416502,104.9815785601,114.5116411118,102.9815785601],
    [124.326595688,100.9815785601,126.6359967648,100.9815785601,127.7906973032,102.9815785601,126.6359967648,104.9815785601,124.326595688,104.9815785601,123.1718951496,102.9815785601],
  ];

// get the average x and y values of each array
var averageTracker = []
for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    var xSum = 0;
    var ySum = 0;
    for (let y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            xSum = xSum + arr[x][y];
        } else {
            ySum = ySum + arr[x][y];
        }
    }
    // save the average x and y value of a hexagon against the index of the hexagon
    var indexTracker = {
        arrayPosition: x,
        xAverage: xSum / (arr[x].length / 2),
        yAverage: ySum / (arr[x].length / 2),
    };
    averageTracker.push(indexTracker);
}

// sort the hexagons by y descending, followed by x ascending
averageTracker.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.yAverage - a.yAverage || a.xAverage - b.xAverage;
});

// get the hexagon out of the original array by index
var newArr = [];
for (let x = 0; x < averageTracker.length; x++) {
    newArr.push(arr[averageTracker[x].arrayPosition]);
}
```

Comment: so i checked it, and it seems to work (on the first glimpse) even with different sized hexagons.
thank you!

Comment: I'm not really sure why I decided to average - I pribably thought it would be less code. Looking at it now, it would be a lot safer to add the x and y values of each hexagon to a temporary array, find the minimum of that array, then use xMin and yMin instead of xAverage and yAverage. The current approach will fall down if you have different sized hexagons that overlap. I'll leave that for you to change though -

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this as plain javascript you need to add CDN for `lodash` library
or you are using javascript framework and library you need to install `lodash`

`$ yarn add lodash / npm install lodash`

on the current page or component use lodash using

```
const _ = require('lodash'); or import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

you are good to go

```
const coordinatesArray = _.map(arr, (row) => {
  // convert every row element into chank of two element
  const coordinates = _.chunk(row, 2)
  // convert coordinates into readable form using x and y axis
  return _.map(coordinates, (i) => ({ x: i[0], y: i[1] }))
})
const sortedCoordinates = _.map(coordinatesArray, (row) => {
  // sort array based on x axis you can change ASC DESC
  return _.sortBy(row, 'x')
})
const sortHexagons = _.map(sortedCoordinates, (row) => {
  const newrow = []
  // deconstruct corrdinated into array of array form to get desicre result
  _.map(row, (i) => {
    // deconstruction on coordination
    newrow.push(i.x)
    newrow.push(i.y)
  })
  return newrow
})
// required result 
console.log(sortHexagons)
```